# Appending paragraph numbers to table of contents headings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bit of a problem here that I can't seem to solve for the life of me.

I have a page of text structured like so:

```
<h2>Main heading</h2>

<p>
<span class="paranum">1</span>
Nam a dapibus felis, id adipiscing libero. 
Aliquam volutpat vel metus at molestie. Curabitur gravida sed justo at feugiat. 
In ut pellentesque lorem. Nunc mollis, libero a vestibulum pharetra, neque enim 
lacinia odio, ut dignissim nisl lectus vitae nisl. Curabitur ac erat nibh. 
Suspendisse posuere vitae metus at semper. Aliquam vitae tellus id nulla porttitor
 pellentesque at nec elit. Sed nec arcu quis est eleifend gravida.</p>

<p>
<span class="paranum">2</span>
Nam a dapibus felis, id adipiscing libero. Aliquam
volutpat vel metus at molestie. Curabitur gravida sed justo at feugiat. In ut 
pellentesque lorem. Nunc mollis, libero a vestibulum pharetra, neque enim lacinia odio,
ut dignissim nisl lectus vitae nisl. Curabitur ac erat nibh. Suspendisse posuere vitae
metus at semper. Aliquam vitae tellus id nulla porttitor pellentesque at nec elit. 
Sed nec arcu quis est eleifend gravida.</p>
```

At the top of my page, I have a table of contents, generated at runtime by the CMS:

```
<ul class="table-of-contents">
    <li><a href="#heading1">Heading 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#mainheading">Main heading</a></li>
    <li><a href="#aheading">A heading</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using `JavaScript` or `jQuery` (or any other method people could suggest!) I need to find a way of grabbing the paragraph numbers (defined by the class `paranum`) found underneath the headings on the page, and displaying them inline with the table of contents, like so:

[image: Table of contents]

Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: Do the `h2` elements have the ids as set in the `href` of the anchor?

Comment: They don't. The anchors we're using are in a span above the headings themselves, in order to avoid an overlapping issue we were having with the top nav.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a id inside each heading, which you use to link to the heading anyway.

```
<h2 id="mainheading">Main heading</h2>
```

Collect the first and last paranum with jQuery:

```
var paranums = $(id).find('.paranum');
var firstnum = $('#'+id+' .paranum:first'),
    lastnum = $('#'+id+' .paranum:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get all paranum class values :

```
   $('.paranum').each(function () 
   {
       var li = $("<li></li>");
       li.append(this.html());

       $(".table-of-contents").append(li);
   });
```

//note put this in onclick event.